# KDE Plasmoid how to override Text displayed when hovered over the plasmoid

Tags: qml, plasmoid

If I hover over my plasmoid, it displays the string specified as comment in the metadata.desktop. But if I for example hover over the battery-icon, it displays the percentage.

Is there any function to override this behavior and display an other comment in QML?